# Javascript: How to concatenate two or more variables in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to combine two or more variables into the same array index but not do anything to the values, just place them together in the same array index

So

```
 var myArray[];
 var one= 1;
 var two = 2;
 etc...
 myArray.push("one" + "two") 
 document.write(myArray[0];
```

Should output 12 or 1 2 but not add them together to show 3.

Comment: Just concatenate them together, perhaps with a space in between?

Comment: what do you mean by *place them together in the same array index*?

Comment: What's the question here? how to convert a number into a string? or even more basic, like what's the difference between the two? Or what's the difference between adding two numbers and concatenating two strings?

Comment: How to concatenate two variables lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove double quotes and for converting to string just add a `''` between them. This kind of converting is more efficience than `String()`

```js
var myArray = [];
var one = 1;
var two = 2;
myArray.push(one + '' + two)
document.write(myArray[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, using `String` to convert the numbers into strings and then `+` will perform string concatenation instead of numeric addition.

```js
const myArray = [];
const one = 1;
const two = 2;

myArray.push(String(one) + String(two));
console.log(myArray);
```